# Error Node Heroku deployement. express not found

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, web-deployment, mern

I am trying to deploy nodejs app with some getter and setter, but unable to deploy.
I have opted for nodejs environment on heroku and provided enviriment variable also
but it is showing error related to express.

```
Jul 24 10:18:04 PM  node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:949
Jul 24 10:18:04 PM    throw err;
Jul 24 10:18:04 PM    ^
Jul 24 10:18:04 PM  
Jul 24 10:18:04 PM  Error: Cannot find module 'express'
Jul 24 10:18:04 PM  Require stack:
 - /opt/render/project/src/index.js
Jul 24 10:18:04 PM      at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:946:15)
Jul 24 10:18:04 PM      at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:787:27)
Jul 24 10:18:04 PM      at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1012:19)
Jul 24 10:18:04 PM      at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
Jul 24 10:18:04 PM      at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/render/project/src/index.js:1:17)
Jul 24 10:18:04 PM      at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1112:14)
Jul 24 10:18:04 PM      at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1166:10)
Jul 24 10:18:04 PM      at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)
Jul 24 10:18:04 PM      at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:834:12)
Jul 24 10:18:04 PM      at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12) {
Jul 24 10:18:04 PM    code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
Jul 24 10:18:04 PM    requireStack: [ '/opt/render/project/src/index.js' ]
Jul 24 10:18:04 PM  }
Jul 24 10:18:04 PM  
Jul 24 10:18:04 PM  Node.js v18.5.0
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "linktree_back",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js --ext js",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js --exec 'npm start -s"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.7.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.14.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.3.5",
    "mongoose-unique-validator": "^3.1.0",
    "node": "^18.5.0"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "example",
    "heroku"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19"
  }
}
```

**I am importing express like this in index.js**
`const express = require("express");`
also server

```
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URL)
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running npm install, which will make sure that all your package specified in the package.json are installed. Then deploy your app to Heroku. Or, if you know that you are only missing express, just install express by itself by running:

```
npm install express
```

Your app is looking for the express module and can't find it because it does not exist.